# C++ Builder: Abnormal program termination. How to investigate?

Tags: c++builder

I'm trying to move a project that was done in a previous version of C++Builder to 10.1 Berlin (I am using the trial version of C++Builder).

The project was converted and compiled succefully with minimal efforts. Then I got the well-known linker LME288 problem, but it was resolved by starting C++Builder as an administrator.

But now, when I start the application, I get a message box saying "Abnormal program termination" at the very beginning - even before the main window appears on screen.

The situation is the same for debug and release versions, under IDE and as standalone. When I start the program inside the IDE, and set a breakpoint at the very first statement, the error message appears before this statement.

I have Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit. C++Builer 10.1 Berlin trial.  It shows the only accessible platform is Win32, but I don't know if this is a reason for an error. The program worked fine for previous versions.

Could anybody advise me what to do? Is there a systematic way of investigating the problem?

I have tried all recommendations I could found - use debugger, show us the code, try reinstalling software or Windows, upgrade to latest updates, etc. But I have never seen a systematic approach.

Comment: When you run the project in the debugger, what does it actually show you? Your breakpoint is obviously too late in the execution, but the debugger should still see the failure happen, and especially report the memory address of the failure, and let you debug the process, look at the call stack, the CPU registers, etc.  `main()`/`WinMain()` is not the first code that the EXE runs.

Comment: @Remy My mistake - it appears I pressed "Run without debugger" (green arrow) instead of Run. Now I see debugger note: "Project  raised exception class EReadError with message 'Error reading TreeView.Indent: System Error.  Code: 1410. Class already exists'.
Nevertheless still don't understand the reason. Up to now found a suggestion that the automatic conversion from old to new project was made incorrectly. Is it possible taking in account that compile and link was successful?

Comment: That error does not make sense. `EReadError` is a DFM streaming error, but the `Indent` property is just an integer, it shouldn't be doing anything with classes.  And error 1410 is `ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS`, which is not something the DFM streaming system would throw anyway since it doesn't register classes during streaming.  Again, I suggest you use the debugger to look at the call stack and find the code that is causing the error.

Comment: If you have CodeGuard in your IDE installed try to turn it on (not sure if you got it my BDS2006 does) it will stop on first error (not crash) so you can see what is actually happening but it is not usable on big projects ... as it is slow and usually overflows memory usage ... my bet is you got some nasty  memory leak or const string pointer arithmetics error (those were bugging me for ported projects a lot) these usually kicks in before The forms creation.

Comment: @Remy  CodeGuard is already turned on. Error is happend on a statement in main file:   'Application->CreateForm(__classid(TACartDialog), &ACartDialog);'

Comment: Here is the head of stack:  
:7412a882 KERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x62
:00613C11 System::Sysutils::RaiseLastOSError(LastError=????, AdditionalInfo=????)
:00613B8C System::Sysutils::RaiseLastOSError()
:00828B2E Vcl::Forms::TScrollingWinControl::CreateWnd(Self=????)
:0069FA79 System::Classes::TReader::ReadProperty(Self=:02A7E750, AInstance=:02A0F8C0)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things I had to do to get my project working.

1) Start a new project.  For some reason old projects can get corrupted and produce strange errors.  I recommend starting a new project and adding your files to it.
2) Use an old version of borlndmm.dll  The version provided with C++ Builder 10 produced crashes for me that made no sense.  I overwrote the provided copy of borlndmm.dll with a copy from XE6 or XE8.  That solved my problem.

Hopefully one of these will help you.

Comment: Making a new project each time you upgrade C++Builder version avoids a lot of weird problems